# UnsupportedTemporalTypeException thrown for OFFSET_SECONDS when calling format(BASIC_ISO_DATE) on LocalDate instance

Tags: java-8, java-time

I turned on break on all exceptions within my IDE and am seeing `UnsupportedTemporalTypeException` pop up on every call to `localDateInstance.format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE)`.

**Is this normal behavior or is this a bug?**

The stack trace is in the `get0` method of `LocalDate` and the parameter passed is `OFFSET_SECONDS`.

Looking further, I see that BASIC_ISO_DATE is defined as follows:

```
    BASIC_ISO_DATE = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendValue(YEAR, 4)
            .appendValue(MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
            .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendOffset("+HHMMss", "Z")
            .toFormatter(ResolverStyle.STRICT, IsoChronology.INSTANCE);
```

The offending bit looks like the `.optionalStart()` section with the timezone offset.

I would argue that this is sloppy design/implementation of the standard library here. An optional formatting section should not cause an exception to be thrown and caught, slowing down performance, unbeknownst to the user of the library.

Comment: The exception doesn't get thrown up to the line calling `format`; it gets thrown and caught somewhere down the stack before returning. Did you enable break on all exceptions in your IDE? I don't have any specific code example.

Comment: Are you formatting dates at a rate that you actually notice a performance drop due to this design flaw? If so, you should file a bug report, if not, well, you may still file a bug report about the bad design, though it’s not noticeable from the outside. I doubt that discussing it, is within the scope of SO and, well, if we start discussing every code smell within the JRE implementation, SO would explode…

Comment: Yes, this is normal behaviour but also bad because performance drops down due to internal throwing and catching the observed exception. As Holger said, you could file a bug report, or you try to reduce the usage of optional formatting sections in your app or you try out my library Time4J which has a better format engine. See also [this example](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/ce38ede895995012013dd4a7b754e8cd).